# How to interpret iframe info from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I need to know the full url for an iframe in a particular website. In IE and Chrome all I could easily determine is the main url for the iframe which when I open in a new  window does not show the correct results. The reason for this is as there is some info being passed from the main window which tells the iframe how to open.

In Chrome under 'inspect element' I see under 'network' and below that in 'headers' that:

Query String paramaters
event=filter

From Data
search_options%red%4A=green&search_options=red

Its a much longer string. How can I use this info to find out the full URL to open up directly. Or is there another way to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click in the frame and click `View Frame Source`.

You will then see in the address bar the full URL that the frame was loaded from.

However, if the frame was loaded from a POST request, you will only be able to see the POST data in the inspector.

Comment: it most likely was from a POST request. forgive me but I'm not that well versed in these matters, how can I see the post data and combine that into one full url